# How to send already signed DocuSign to recipients?

Tags: templates, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign rest api for sending embedded DocuSign to receipts in my PHP application. How can I set prefilled signature of any person( may be its manager/HR...not mine) in the DocuSign template before sending the envelop to the recipients.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-filling signatures cannot be done via the API if you mean an actual person's signature. This has to be done by the signer/recipient.

You can have a flow where you have a recipient sign, then the envelope is routed with their signature to the recipients and they'll see the first signature already in there.

If you want to circumvent this restriction you can take a screenshot of a signature and add it to a document as an image. I would highly discourage doing this because it may be misleading from the recipients.